# Unpacking "the rest" of the elements in list comprehension - python3to2

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, tuples, python-2.x

In Python 3, I could use `for i, *items in tuple` to isolate the first time from the tuple and the rest into items, e.g.:

```
>>> x = [(2, '_', 'loves', 'love', 'VBZ', 'VBZ', '_', '0', 'ROOT', '_', '_'), (1, '_', 'John', 'John', 'NNP', 'NNP', '_', '2', 'nsubj', '_', '_'), (3, '_', 'Mary', 'Mary', 'NNP', 'NNP', '_', '2', 'dobj', '_', '_'), (4, '_', '.', '.', '.', '.', '_', '2', 'punct', '_', '_')]
>>> [items for n, *items in sorted(x)]
[['_', 'John', 'John', 'NNP', 'NNP', '_', '2', 'nsubj', '_', '_'], ['_', 'loves', 'love', 'VBZ', 'VBZ', '_', '0', 'ROOT', '_', '_'], ['_', 'Mary', 'Mary', 'NNP', 'NNP', '_', '2', 'dobj', '_', '_'], ['_', '.', '.', '.', '.', '_', '2', 'punct', '_', '_']]
```

I need to backport this to Python 2 and I can't use the `*` pointer to collect the rest of the items in the tuple.

- What is the equivalent in Python 2?
- Is it still possible to achieve the same using the list comprehension?
- What is the technical name for this `*` usage? Unpacking? Isolating? Pointers?
- Is there a `__future__` import that can be used such that I can use the same syntax in Python 2?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use slicing to skip the first element:

```
[all_items[1:] for all_items in sorted(x)]
```

The syntax is referred to *extended tuple unpacking*, where the `*`-prefixed name is called the *catch-all name*. See [PEP 3132](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/). There is no backport of the syntax.

Comment: Ooooh *extended tuple unpacking* ;P Thanks @MartijnPieters!!

Comment: short question, in the case of `zip(*list_of_tuples)`, would the `*` prefix be called something else, or is it also a *catch-all name*?

Comment: @alvas: there isn't really a satisfactory name for that syntax. I do use *catch-all* in this context too, but it's an argument now, so *catch-all argument* and for the double-star version *catch-all keyword argument*.

Comment: Isn't that "argument unpacking"? Or is that something else?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: That's the other side, in the call syntax. `result = some_callable(*iterable)`.

Comment: Wouldn't `zip(*list_of_tuples)` be `some_callable(*iterable)`?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: erm. Oops, yes it is. And the name of the parameter is then not a catch-all either. I'm not aware of any official names here other than the technique.